# Using Azure Server to send FCM message to topic doesn't work

Tags: azure, firebase, xamarin.android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send message to topic from my C# code using azure server to android app but it doesn't work, not sure azure blocking to send message or not. Here is my code snippet :

```
public static void SendNoticeToFcmServer(string id, string title, string apiUrl,string key)
        {
            var jFcmData = new JObject();
            var jData = new JObject();

            jData.Add("body", title);
            jData.Add("sound", "default");
            jFcmData.Add("to", "/topics/" + id);
            jFcmData.Add("priority", "high");
            jFcmData.Add("notification", jData);

            var url = new Uri(apiUrl);

            using (var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler()))
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(
                    "Authorization", "key=" + key);

                Task.WaitAll(client.PostAsync(url,
                    new StringContent(jFcmData.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
                        .ContinueWith(response =>
                        {

                        }));
            }

        }
```

Comment: Are you positive that the particular device(s) are properly subscribed to that topic? Is the response showing any error? Do you have any client side code you could share?

Comment: I am getting notification on my device when I run my web application that implemented above code in my local host or real ip but when I deploy my code to azure server no notification coming. My device is subscribing the topic properly. Even I have tested creating a console application and getting notification.